# Multithreading for convolution calculation

Tags: c++, multithreading, camera, convolution

I am trying to calculate the convolution product the two pictures from two cameras as fast as possible. The cameras output ~ 17 fps, each frame is ~3MB. The camera manufacturer provides some c/c++ libraries to capture the images, all I need to do is to fourier transform each image, multiply the corresponding fourier transforms and make an inverse transform. What I currently do is I create a buffer and fill it with the frames in one thread, and there are three more threads, two for fourier transforming images from each camera and one for multiplication and calculation of the inverse fourier transforms.

At certain moment it becomes hard to pair the corresponding frames. I assign unique IDs to each frame when it is created. And when a new frame arrives I check if there are any frames with the same ID from the other camera. At certain moment it becomes hard to tell if it is a new frame in sequence and I need to put it to buffer and wait for the pair, or I've lost too many frames from the other camera and I need to discard this to catch it up.

What data types is it better to use and how to organize the data flow?

Comment: Do you need help tagging frames? That sounds way easier than the title suggested to, which is making a convolution multithreaded.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "corresponding".  What is the constraint?

Comment: By corresponding I mean taken at the same moment of time (the cameras will be synchronized with an external trigger). However due to asynchronous character of the data transfer, they do not arrive at the same time into the program.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here really. How big is your convolution kernel? What processor type are u using (SSE/SSE2/MKL/MKL512)? Double/float precision (why)? How do you implement your complex multiplication? Why do you tag your frames. Why is your buffer not just #points times n frames. So the beginning of every frame and its according frame # corresponds to just a position in the buffer. There is a lot of things to be considered depending on those details. Do you use FFTW/MKL own FFT? Etc. etc. etc.